# Installing CKAN 2.8.2 in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: database

I am trying to install CKAN 2.8.2 in Ubuntu 18.04 following these [instructions](https://docs.ckan.org/en/2.8/maintaining/installing/install-from-package.html).

I have followed all steps successfully, until step 4.2 with sudo ckan db init.

I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/ckan", line 4, in <module>
    from pkg_resources import load_entry_point
  File "/usr/lib/ckan/default/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 84, in <module>
    __import__('pkg_resources.extern.packaging.requirements')
  File "/usr/lib/ckan/default/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/extern/__init__.py", line 61, in load_module
    "distribution.".format(**locals())
ImportError: The 'packaging.requirements' package is required; normally this is bundled with this package so if you get this warning, consult the packager of your distribution.
```

Any ideas on what is wrong?

Answer (score 1):

The error is pretty clear about it

> ImportError: The 'packaging.requirements' package is required; normally this is bundled with this package so if you get this warning, consult the packager of your distribution.

The link you have in the question states

> but it requires Ubuntu 16.04 64-bit or Ubuntu 14.04 64-bit

So that excludes 18.04 what you are installing.

As stated in the error: take it up with the maintainer to adjust the package to include the requirements for 18.04

As a general guide: packages outside of the Ubuntu system that belong to a lower LTS tend to NOT work since we switch a lot of the core features between LTS releases (the switch from unity to gnome for instance happened in between 16.04 and 18.04)